# How to solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException"

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am using marionette driver for testing with selenium. when I run the code it gives me the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException.

Also gives error :

> Found argument '--webdriver-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

Please help for the same

I have used "java-json.jar" however now it's give the error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:" so can you suggest what issue is for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding java-json/.jar in your classpath.
Download the jar from [Jar link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)